# How to bind model to view for showing the data in inout textboxes.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have been just started with MVC4 razor view. As of now i have done save, and listing of records. Now i am trying to do Edit of a record. But i am not able to bind the data in model object from controller to view input elements. Could someone help me in this context.?

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PersonAction", "Admin"))
{
  <input type="submit" name="SubmitAction" value="New" id="btnNew" tabindex="65" title="New" class="btnInner-Save btnInner-size" />

  <input type="submit" name="SubmitAction" value="Edit" id="btnEdit" tabindex="65" title="Edit" class="btnInner-Save btnInner-size" />
  <div class="div2col-S">
    <label id="lblFirstName" for="Name1">First Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name1) </div> <div class="div2col-S">
    <label id="lblSecondName" for="Name2">Second Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name2)
  </div>
}
```

**Model**

```
public class person
{
  public virtual string Name1
  {
    get { return this._name1; }
    set { this._name1 = value; }
  }

  public virtual string Name2
  {
    get { return this._name2; }
    set { this._name2 = value; }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Person()
    {
        var persongrdList = new PersonBusiness().GetList();
        ViewBag.PersonGridList = persongrdList;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersonAction(string SubmitAction, Person mdl)
    {
        switch (SubmitAction)
        {
            case Constants.NEW_ACTION:
                break;
            case Constants.EDIT_ACTION:
                Person p = new PersonBusiness().GetByPrimaryKey(mdl.PersonID);
                ViewBag.SelectedRecord = p;//Need help over here. How to bind this person model data to view input elements?
                break;
            case Constants.SAVE_ACTION:
                bool success = new PersonBusiness().Insert(mdl, 1);

                break;
            case Constants.CANCEL_ACTION:
                break;

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Person", "Admin");

    }
}
```

Comment: where is your edit action?

Comment: Sorry i just added the input element and BeginForm method

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your model like this:

```
var personDetails = new PersonDetails()
var p = new PersonBusiness().GetByPrimaryKey(mdl.PersonID);

personDetails.Name1 = p.Name1;
personDetails.Name2 = p.Name2;

return View("ViewName", new SmartClinic.Models.Person { PersonDetails = personDetails });
```

Once returned in view:

```
@model SmartClinic.Models.PersonDetails
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name2)
```

**Update**

```
public class Person
{
   public PersonDetails PersonDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetails 
{
     public string Name1 { get; set; }
     public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this code is already there beginning of my view; @{
    Layout = null;
}
@model SmartClinic.Models.Person

Comment: To return the list do the first snippet in my answer, then m => m.Person[0].Name will get your values into the textboxes, this is the issue right? not binding the values to the textboxes?

Comment: edited above is that what your after? just return p object to the view.

Comment: I just tried in this way:                     return View("Person", (SmartClinic.Models.Person)p); . Still not working

Comment: But in my view it is still like -> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name1)

Comment: Getting this error-> 'SmartClinic.Models' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: return View("ViewName", new SmartClinic.Models.Person { PersonDetails = personDetails });

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have some change:

### Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

You should Create PersonController and have a index action to list people:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    return View(people);
}
```

GetMethod to make model(person) and send it to view:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Person p = new PersonBusiness().GetByPrimaryKey(id);
    return View(p);
}
```

PostMethod to edit the model that posted to action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Person p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var peopleToEdit = new Person
        {
            Name1 = p.Name1,
            Name2 = p.Name2
        };
        //Commit your change
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View("Edit", p);
}
```

### Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Person>
//List your persons and a button to edit for every person
```

### Edit View:

```
@model Person
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name2)
    //...
}
```